# Dreamweaver CSS <--[if IE]>

Tags: css, if-statement, dreamweaver, flash-cs5

I'm working on a small website, but of course IE doesn't view it the same as Chrome or Firefox do. I've read around and found using `<--[if IE]>` *should* make only IE use the stylesheet I need.

When I was using Microsoft Expression on a different PC earlier, it worked fine. I came home and started editing in Dreamweaver CS5, now it doesn't work as it should.

I researched it a little and I know that Dreamweaver views it as a comment rather than an `if` function.

So how can I fix/get around this?

Thanks in advance!

P.S. The whole piece of code I'm using is `<!--[if IE ]> <link href="IEcss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> <![endif]-->`

**Edit:** I found the answer, I had to close the comment tag before referencing the stylesheet. http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Comment: Coding with Expression AND DW??? ohh good lord. O_o

Comment: The only coding program my school has is Expression, I wish I had a choice against it. :P

Comment: well for home you have no excuse then :P [Geany](http://www.geany.org/), [VIM](http://www.vim.org/), [notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/), [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2), [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)  Choose your weapon.

Answer (score 2):

You have a space after `IE`:

```
<!--[if IE ]>
```

Should be:

```
<!--[if IE]>
```

Other than that, it looks correct. But the space may very well be throwing it off, because conditional comments have to match an *exact* syntax – otherwise they get interpreted as regular comments and ignored.

Comment: Well I tried taking out that space and tried random other things, still not working. I'm pretty confused.

Answer (score 0):

**Design-Time** style sheets allow you to show or hide design applied by a CSS style sheet as you work in a Dreamweaver document. For example, you can use this option to include or exclude the effect of a Macintosh-only or a Windows-only style sheet as you design a page.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/using/WScbb6b82af5544594822510a94ae8d65-7e17a.html